# How to calculate the amount of letters written in a txt file

Tags: java, file, stream, filereader

i'd like to know whether there is an easy way to count the letters in a txt file.
Lets say i have different txt files with a different amount of letters written in it, and i want to delete all txt files which have more letters than lets say 2000.
Furthermore let's assume i deal with one txt at a time. I've tried this so far:

```
FileReader reader2 = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Internet\\eclipse-workspace\\test2.txt");
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(reader2)){

int counter = 0;

            while(buff.ready()){
                String aa = buff.readLine();
                counter = counter + aa.length();

            }
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is there an easier way or one which has better performance?
Reading all letters in a String to just discard them afterwards seems like a lot of timewaste.
Should i maybe use an InputStream and use available() and then divide? On the other hand i saw that available() counts literally everything like when i press Enter in the txt file it adds +2 to the amount of letters.
Thanks for all answers.

Comment: What about [`java.nio.file.Files.lines(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)?

Comment: You are counting the number of characters, not the number of letters. So that's why you're getting +2 amount of letters ("\r\n"). You should remove all special characters from the string, and there are a lot of methods to do this.

Comment: Are we dealing with UTF-8/16 or other charsets with variable byte count per charcter? If we're not, just use File.size() and divide it by the number of bytes per character in your charset. HOWEVER this will also count EVERY character - including newlines (which is `\r\n` and therefore 2 bytes on windows). You can use File.lines to count the newlines and the subtract.

Comment: Thank you. It seems i checked the Oracle Documentation for Java 7 not 8. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html.

Comment: Java 7 has `.size()` as well, just no `.lines()` - so you'd need another way to account for newlines if you absolutely do not want to count them.

Comment: I just tried using Files.lines but it kinda comes down to what i had before because it saves all the lines as a String in a Stream. In my case i have 4 Strings. The thing is that i'd like to know how many letters i have. To calculate that i have to get the length of the String and add it to a counter. Seems like there is no better way around it ^^ Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Files.lines` as below,

```
counter = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Internet\\eclipse-workspace\\test2.txt"))
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        .sum();
```

Comment: Thank you.That really helped. Didnt think about mapping the Strings to their length and adding them together. Kinda comes down to what i had but looks way nicer.